# re.findall multiple literals

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am using this code to return all of the numbers in a string called myString.

```
re.findall(r'\d+', myString)
```

Sometimes I run into a problem when a dash ('-') will be present in place of one or more the numbers.  I would like to return the dash along with the numbers if it is present.

My question is how to I change the code so that this '-' character is returned with along the numbers in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a character class for `\d` and `\-` like this

```
re.findall(r'[\d\-]+', myString)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7b81x9gtf-RBn4Zm)

Comment: Be careful! If you have any fields in the string like "12-27-2004", they will be returned as a single value. This may not be what you intended.

Comment: \-(?=\d)|[\d]+|(?<=\d)\-   if you want to leave out stand alone '-'

Answer (score 0):

```
sample = "1a d g23 -49xy d-d j-4 29"
re.findall(r"\d+|-\d*", sample)
```

returns

```
['1', '23', '-49', '-', '-4', '29']
```